# Dynamic Name for Scope in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to generate the name of a scope variable dynamically and then use it in `ng-repeat` on my html page.  I honestly don't know how to begin.  What I need is something like:

In my controller:

```
$scope.[myDynamicName] = Section1;
$scope.[myDynamicName] = Section2;
```

Then in my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myDynamicName(Section1)"> here myDynamicName would be replaced with Section1
<div ng-repeat="item in myDynamicName(Section2)"> here myDynamicName would be replaced with Section2
```

The issue is that I have several arrays that need to appear on 1 page.  The arrays are filled as the user chooses which sections they want to view.  There are over 100 sections (and new ones are being created all the time) and the user can choose any combination of sections to view on the page so I can't just give them static names.  I tried using an example I found on SO `$scope[field]=Section1` then in my html `ng-repeat = q in field`, but of course, that didn't work.

Currently, I get the response for each section using the section ID in a service call like below:

```
            deferred.resolve(contractorService.getQuestionSectionAnswers(id)
          .success(function (data) {
            $scope.questions = data;
```

I can't use `$scope.questions` for each set on the same page.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on how the dynamic variable will be generated for the user to choose from?  are you going to be getting a list, or using some service, or something else?

Comment: The user selects sections via checkboxes which collects the section numbers needed.  Then a service is called to get the information for each section, so every time the data comes back from the service for a particular section, I need to name a scope variable for that section.  I may be going about this all wrong, but I'm not sure how else to get what is needed.

Comment: ok, so the user has a list of sections to choose from, then they select a few, which sends an array of section numbers to the service.  the service then makes a call out for each section number, right?  so either (a) the service returns an array of section arrays, or (b) the service returns a bunch of different arrays, identified by their section number, right?

Comment: The call for each section returns a list of items for that section.

Comment: right, so what do those service calls look like? can you show some pseudo of how you make these calls and how you are storing what gets returned?

Comment: deferred.resolve(contractorService.getQuestionSectionAnswers(id)
              .success(function (data) {
                $scope.questions = data;  It uses id of question section in a forEach to get each list.  However, using ng-repeat="q in questions" just gives me the last $scope.questions over and over.

Comment: it would be best if you [edit] the question with that code.... that being said, that's only returning one list, `$scope.questions`.  what are you doing when more than one list is fetched?

Comment: yes, indeed, it would only give you the last one, because you are overwriting the `$scope.questions` array every time.

Comment: Is there a way I can push all of the lists into an array and then do a ng-repeat on that, like ng-repeat="L in mySectionList" then ng-repeat="q in L.questions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested, obviously).

First, create an array to hold the results groups.

```
$scope.sectionAnswers = [];
```

Next, when you fetch the results for a specific group, you can push the result list into the array:

```
deferred.resolve(contractorService.getQuestionSectionAnswers(id)
      .success(function (data) {
        $scope.sectionAnswers.push(data);
      }))
```

Then, you can iterate through the array, and then iterate through the sub-array:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sectionAnswers">
  <div ng-repeat="answer in section">
    {{answer.field}}
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user de-selects the checkbox, you then simply remove the associated `answers` from the array.

Comment: LOL!  I just asked in my comment if I could do something like this.  I'm going to try it.  Thanks!

Comment: also, you might want to switch to `.then()` instead of the deprecated `.success()`, and if `getQuestionSectionAnswers` is using `$http`, you don't need to wrap the response in a promise, because `$http` returns a promise natively.